# How can I modify the WordPress .htaccess file to redirect specific requests to a Node app and preserve params

Tags: node.js, wordpress, .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file at the root of my wordpress install that looks like this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Next to this file is `events/event` directories which contains another .htaccess that looks like this.

```
PassengerAppRoot "/home/user/example.com/build_repo"
PassengerBaseURI "/events/event"
PassengerNodejs "/home/user/nodevenv/example.com/build_repo/10/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile server.js
```

WordPress is working as expected and if I visit `example.com/events/event` the node app runs, but what I need is for a request that looks like `example.com/events/event/event_name` to still run the node app (it currently goes back to wordpress) and preserve the "event_name" so the node app has what it needs to make an API request. How would I modify the .htaccess files to make that happen?

Comment: If you add `RewriteRule ^events/event - [L]` after the first rule, that should probably do the trick already.

Comment: This is working @CBroe , however I had WordPress returning a page at the `example.com/events` path, and it is now returning a directory listing. I should have made that clear in my question. Is there a way to accomplish both so that the node app runs when the full `events/event` path is hit, and WordPress picks up on the `events` path. At any rate, please submit your answer and I will give you credit regardless

Comment: Hm, not sure how that worked before than, actually. Since `/events` physically exists, that should have bypassed the WP routing to begin with. But explicitly rewriting it to the index.php now should be able to fix that, too, I suppose. Try `RewriteRule ^events$ /index.php [L]`, inserted before or after the other new rule for `events/event`. If that works, I’ll consolidate it into an answer.

Comment: @CBroe , that didn't quite work. the `events` route was still loading the directory. I thought it might be easier if I moved some things around a little. Now there is no `events` directory, only an `event` directory. The node app is pointed to this `event` directory and the htaccess has only `RewriteRule ^event - [L]` as a new rule. That is working as expected. I thought the 'events' route would work correctly now, but I'm only getting the WordPress index.php file so I know WP is handling it, but the correct template isn't picking it up? I've tried bumping the files but that's not working.

Comment: `^event` still matches `events` - you need `^event$` if you want it to match _just_ `event`, and nothing whatsoever after it.